# Как уменьшить нагрузку на базу mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

У меня есть порядка 150 000 строк которые нужно вставлять (insert) в базу данных mysql.

Сейчас я делаю insert на каждую строку, то есть получается 150 000 запросов идет. В итоге я получаю зависание приложения, и ошибки `too many connections`

в настройках mysql max connections = 150, увеличить тоже не вариант, потому что серверу не хватит ОЗУ и он упадет...

Можно ли как-то делать один insert и в него передавать все строки?

Фрагмент кода моего php скрипта:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", 'base', 'pass', 'user');
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Не удалось подключиться к базе данных: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error); exit();
}

foreach ($arr as $key => $v) {
    $mysqli->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO `table` (`row1`, `row2`) VALUES ('$v[val1]', '$v[val2]')");
    $id = mysqli_insert_id($mysqli);
}
```

Comment: `too many connections` у вас получается не потому, что на каждую строку у вас отдельный запрос, а потому что вы делаете это в цикле, каждый раз создавая новое подключение, и, видимо, не закрывая его.

Comment: @teran у меня подключение `$mysqli = new mysqli(...);` только 1 раз, в начале скрипта. далее я в цикле делаю `insert'ы` просто. разве нужно в цикле закрывать и открывать новое соединение? буду благодарен за информацию!

Comment: текст ошибки явно говорит, что подключения множатся по той или иной причине. Если бы вы привели фрагменты кода, было куда понятнее.

Comment: @teran добавил фрагмент кода в вопрос

Comment: если на этом цикл заканчивается, то зачем id сохранять в переменную? Там не такого, что этот ID подставляется еще в один запрос, который в свою очердь создает коннект?

Comment: @teran этот id мне нужен будет очень скоро. так в приведенном примере кода есть проблема о которой вы говорили? (не закрываю соединения)

Comment: в приведенном примере проблемы нет. но это не значит что ее нет в принципе. В любом случае, вам уже дан совет о том, что данные надо вставлять пачками, а не по одной строке.

Comment: @teran я так и сделал -  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1499508/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd-insert-%d1%81-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba/1500793#1500793 - но особой разницы не заметил

Answer (score 2):

Сформируйте запрос таким образом:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (1,2), (5,5), ...;
```

Здесь в скобках указываются данные каждой строки, которую нужно вставить.

Comment: Я бы добавил, что 1) не совсем понятно, почему МНОГО вставок (т.е. запросов) приводят к ошибке превышения лимита соединений? У вас эти 150 000 вставок в рамках чего происходят? 2) одна вставка 150 000 записей тоже может лечь или приводить к ошибке из-за ограничений на размер запроса, поэкспериментируйте с количеством записей успешно вставляемых за один раз, как показано в комментарии выше. Так как вы не привели состав полей, трудно предположить объемы. Попробуйте эмпирически подобрать число записей, вставляемое за один INSERT корректно.